# Check is a radio button is checked after post back in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, http-post

I am looping through all the posted data on my website and grabbing the values, this will then be used later on. The user is going to put 2 radio buttons on the page, one with a correct answer and one with an incorrect answer. I need to know how to see if a Radio Button is checked or not based on the posted data. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the radio button is checked, there will be an entry in the posted data, keyed with its [UniqueID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid.aspx):

```
if (Request.Form[yourRadioButton.UniqueID] != null) {
    // Radio button is checked, do something.
}
```

Comment: Hmm, think I just had a propper blonde moment. I forgot that the value won't be posted unless it it's checked anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on reading directly from the request collection, read `Request.Form["radiobuttonname"]` and it will contain the value of the selected button.

However, it's much better to check the radio button control itself - why can't you do that?

Comment: I won't know where the form will be posted from and the form is created by the user so he won't be able to assign an ASP.NET button control to call a specific postback. THis is the reason I have decided to do it this way.